# ¿WuapiLib es compatible con .Net Framework 2.0?

Tags: c#

Necesito crear un apliación de consola que usando WuapiLib, me liste actualizaciones pendientes, descargue estas actualizaciones e instale estas actualizaciones (todo esto configurable mediante parámetros).

La cosa es que debe ser compatible con .Net Framework 2.0 para arriba... y no encuetro informacion que me diga si esta libreria lo será.

Me he enfrentado muy poquitas veces a desarrollar nada en C#, así que perdonad mi torpeza.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por desgracia no hay mucha documentación sobre en qué versión y en qué si es compatible con .Net Framework 2.0. Solo la [página de MSDN Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/desktop/Wua_Sdk/determining-the-current-version-of-wua) (la cual es no tan útil). En base a mi experiencia personal, puedo decir que es totalmente compatible con .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: Gracias Sebastian!