# Necesito una aplicación que descargue he instale las actualizaciones pendientes, compatible desde .NET 2.0 adelante

Tags: c#, windows, update

Pues el tema está en que estoy intentando usar la libreria WUApiLib, la cosa es que si uso la de windows 10, en un server con 2008 con el .Net 3.5, no va.... 
La pregunta es ¿hay alguna forma de hacer que la aplicación que quiero hacer, sea compatible con con todas las versiones de .Net (al menos desde la 2.0)?

Muchas gracias!
EDITO PARA DA MAS INFORMACIÓN
Esta es la funcion que quiero usar:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using WUApiLib;
namespace WindowsUpdateManager
{
    class Program
    {
    //FUNCION PRINCIPAL
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateSession uSession = new UpdateSession();
            IUpdateSearcher uSearcher = uSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
            ISearchResult uResult = uSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'");

            //Console.WriteLine("check");

            if (uResult.Updates.Count < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No hay actualizaciones pendientes.");
            }
            else if (uResult.Updates.Count > 1)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("checkuno");
                foreach (IUpdate update in uResult.Updates)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(update.Title);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Descargando actualizaciones...");

                UpdateDownloader downloader = uSession.CreateUpdateDownloader();
                //Console.WriteLine("line");
                downloader.Updates = uResult.Updates;
                //Console.WriteLine("line2");
                downloader.Download();
                //Console.WriteLine("line3");

                Console.WriteLine("Actualizaciones descargadas.");

                Console.WriteLine("Actualizando Colecciones...");
                UpdateCollection updatesToInstall = new UpdateCollection();
                foreach (IUpdate update in uResult.Updates)
                {
                    if (update.IsDownloaded) updatesToInstall.Add(update);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Instalar actualizaciones recogidas...");
                IUpdateInstaller installer = uSession.CreateUpdateInstaller();
                //Console.WriteLine("Check1");
                installer.Updates = updatesToInstall;
                //Console.WriteLine("Check2");

                IInstallationResult installationRes = installer.Install();
                //Console.WriteLine("Check3");
                for (int i = 0; i < updatesToInstall.Count; i++)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Check4");
                    if (installationRes.GetUpdateResult(i).HResult == 0)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("Check5");
                        Console.WriteLine("Instalada : " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Instalación Fallida : " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);
                    }

                    Console.Write("pause");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Si ocurre algún error, lo imprimimos 
            Console.WriteLine("Exception", e);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Basicamente esta función lo que hace es descargar e instalar las actualizaciones, para que "using WUApiLib" funcione, tengo que añadir la referencia a "C:\Windows\System32\wuapi.dll".
La cosa es que la dll que importa al compilar, es la de windows 10, en mi caso, y cuando la ejecuto en un windows 2008 R2, que se ha quedado en el.Net 3.5, por ejemplo, no funciona.
La pregunta sería si se podria cargar la librería en el arranque de la aplicación; así la aplicación usaria la Dll disponible en el sistema operativo. Creo que lo que quiero hacer es agregar referencias dinámicamente o usar "reflextion", pero me he pateado todo stark overflow, y no soy apaz de adaptar los ejemplos que veo a este códiog...

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿WuapiLib es compatible con .Net Framework 2.0?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/229501/wuapilib-es-compatible-con-net-framework-2-0)

Comment: porque tienes que ir tan atras hasta .net 2 con la compatibilidad ? esa version del framework ni siquiera tiene soporte. La libreria WUApiLib con que version del framework fue generada?

Comment: Hola Leandro. Tengo que poder ejecutar esta aplicación en cualquier servidor windows, y hay maquinas que llevan windows server 2003 (para echarse las manos a la cabeza) por eso necesito compatibilidad desde la 2.0 hasta la 4.5...
Sobre con que version del framework fue generada la libreria WUApiLib , aqui está el problema, necesito encontrar un modo de que eso sea independiente... 
Algo asi como que el programa busque en la máquina la libreria, en vez de añadir la referecia o algo por el estilo... Pero soy muy nuevo en C# y ni idea de si esto es posible

Comment: pero la aplicacion tiene qe ejecutar local, no puedes ejecutar remoto y acceder a la info de windows update desde otro pc donde si funcione la libreria?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 soporta hasta .Net Framework 4.0, lo mismo que Windows XP.

Comment: Lo que tu dices es posible que se pueda hacer Leandro, lo hablaré con el porgramador jefe, a ver que dice.
Luis, el problema es que los responsables de alguno de estos servidores, no quieren actualizar .Net.